# Making both BufferedImages overlap and transparent

Tags: java, bufferedimage, overlap, imagej

So I have searched this question and got many hits and therefore I was able to come up with the code shown below. I am taking images from ImageStack (ImageJ) and I want to overlap two images which are in dicom format (.dcm). My problem is I want both images to be transparent as they overlap each other. I have checked that the images are different when passing to the overlap function and I have tried many things but I can't seem to make the images transparent, they overlap but they are not transparent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  public BufferedImage overlay(BufferedImage bii, BufferedImage biii){
            BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D go = combined.createGraphics();
            image.setSlice(5);
            ImagePlus hello = new ImagePlus();
            hello.setImage(image.getImage());
            BufferedImage bello = hello.getBufferedImage();
            go.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            go.drawImage(bii,0, 0, null);
            go.drawImage(biii,98, 98, null);
            go.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear); 
            go.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            //go.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
            go.dispose();
            return combined;
        }
```

Main function:

```
        ImageStack stack = image.getStack(); 
        Calibration cal = image.getCalibration(); 
        ImagePlus newImp = new ImagePlus( );
        stack.getSliceLabel(5);
        stack.getProcessor(5); 
        newImp.setCalibration( cal ); 
        ImageProcessor ip = stack.getProcessor(1); // specify number of slice 
        newImp.setProcessor(ip); 


        ImagePlus no3 = new ImagePlus();
        no3.setImage(newImp.getImage());
        BufferedImage bii= no3.getBufferedImage();

        ImagePlus bob = new ImagePlus( );
        stack.getSliceLabel(33);
        stack.getProcessor(33); 
        bob.setCalibration( cal ); 
        ImageProcessor bobp = stack.getProcessor(22); // specify number of slice 
        bob.setProcessor(bobp); 
        ImagePlus hello = new ImagePlus();
        hello.setImage(bob.getImage());
        BufferedImage bello = hello.getBufferedImage();

        BufferedImage overlayy = overlay(bii, bello);
        frame2 = new NFrame(image.getTitle(), image, save);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(overlayy));
        pane.add(jLabel);
        frame2.add(pane);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(frame2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageJ 1.x has only limited support for transparent (ARGB) color images (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/2a1ed6de4693952baf2c47c6e331f61f3f07af8b/ij/io/FileInfo.java#L38-39)).

One way to modify the alpha channel of an ARGB image is using the `getChannel` and `setChannel` methods of `ij.process.ColorProcessor`. See [this BeanShell script](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/macros/bsh/Open_Modify_Save_Alpha_PNG.bsh) for an example.

An easier way to combine two images by overlaying one image on top of another image with a certain opacity is using ImageJ's [overlays](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-11.html#toc-Section-11). The following [BeanShell script](http://fiji.sc/Beanshell_Scripting) (porting it to Java should be straightforward) is a minimal example demonstrating the semi-transparent combination of two images:

```bsh
import ij.IJ;
import ij.gui.ImageRoi;
import ij.gui.Overlay;

imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/leaf.jpg");
imp2 = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/clown.jpg");

ImageRoi roi = new ImageRoi(50, 200, imp2.getProcessor());
roi.setZeroTransparent(false);
roi.setOpacity(0.5);
ovl = new Overlay(roi);

imp.setOverlay(ovl);
imp.show();
```

You can try the script by pasting the code into [Fiji's script editor](http://fiji.sc/Using_the_Script_Editor), choosing *Language > Beanshell*, and pressing *Run*.

This will be the result:

[image: Result of running the beanshell script]

To export/save the image, you should run the *Image > Overlay > Flatten* command, or, in Java/Beanshell:

```
flattenedImp = imp.flatten();
```

Comment: I tried what you did but it did not make the image transparent. The same problem still exists.

Comment: I added an image illustrating the expected result of my script. Isn't this what you get when running the beanshell code above?

Comment: Okay so I got it by using imp2.setRoi(roi1). I'm not using beanshell code, so thats why I wasn't getting it. I tried overlay but it doesn't seem to work on mine. Also can you do this for two or more images?

Comment: You can add multiple `Roi`s to an `Overlay` using [`Overlay#add(ij.gui.Roi)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/gui/Overlay.html), but an `ImagePlus` (itself lacking transparency) can only have one current selection, returned by `ImagePlus#getRoi()`.